# ssh fails silently

Tags: ssh

I have noticed that when I execute a command via `ssh`:

```
ssh myserver.mydomain.com "w"
```

and the command fails, `ssh` does not print any error. Lets say, I have misspelled the hostname of my server and `myserver.mydomain.com` does not exist. I would have expected, `ssh` to report something about `unable to connect to server`. But this is not what happens. Instead, `ssh` just prints nothing. Now, I know that I can get the return code of the last command with `$?`. But this is not enough. I am using this in a script and I would appreciate if `ssh` would be more specific. In `man ssh` there is option `-v`, which however is for debugging and prints way too much info.

Is there any way to make `ssh` print the reason for not succeeding?

Comment: Normally it does. Do you by any chance have a `.ssh/config` containing `Loglevel QUIET`, or an alias for ssh resolving to `ssh -q`?

Comment: you are absolutely right! I had `LogLevel QUIET` in my config, matching everything (`*`) and I completely forgot about it.

Comment: I'll make that an answer, then :-)

Comment: If you want more verbose messaging you can add `-v` switches to `ssh` ala. `ssh -vvv ...`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SSH normally does print out error messages.

There are two ways to disable it:

- In your `.ssh/config`, a line containing

  `Loglevel QUIET`

  will disable all messages.
- Using the option `-q`, or aliasing `ssh` to `ssh -q`, will do the same thing.

So make sure that none of those mechanisms have been used.